# mi programa pide insertar 10 números para meterlos a un vector para luego sumarlos, como hago para sumar todo los números?

Tags: java

Necesito un ciclo for para sumar, este es el código que llevo hasta ahora-

```
 int[] numero = new int [10];
             
     for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
     {  
            System.out.println("Ingrese el numero "); 
            numero[i]= entrada.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una variable que acumule la suma de los elementos ingresados

```
int[] numero = new int [10];
//creamos una variable para acumular la suma
int suma=0

 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
 {  
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero "); 
        numero[i]= entrada.nextInt();
        //agregamos el elemento ingresado al acumulado
        suma=suma+numero[i];
```

Comment: En este sitio, tratamos de no resolver ejercicios...